# Cannot send command IR with HotPI

Tags: raspberry-pi, infrared, lirc

I bought a HotPi a while ago, and decided to use it. So I followed the procedure to configure the IR and after a few hours I was able to IR signals on my Raspberry 1.
But my purpose here is to send IR signals, which I tried, without any luck.

So this is the command I try to do (just for test):

```
irsend SEND_START devinput KEY_POWER ; sleep 3
```

And this is what lircd tells me:

```
lircd-0.9.4c[907]: Notice: accepted new client on /var/run/lirc/lircd
lircd-0.9.4c[907]: Info: Cannot configure the rc device for /dev/lirc0
lircd-0.9.4c[907]: Error: invalid send buffer
lircd-0.9.4c[907]: Error: this remote configuration cannot be used to transmit
lircd-0.9.4c[907]: Error: error processing command: SEND_START devinput KEY_POWER
lircd-0.9.4c[907]: Error: transmission failed
lircd-0.9.4c[907]: Info: removed client
```

Edit:
It seems I'm not using the good drivers. According to the HotPi documentation, I'm suppose to use lirc-rpi, which I'm suppos to install with

```
sudo modprobe lirc-rpi
```

Which, at least, doesn't return an error. But trying to configure the interface tells me that the driver doesn't exist:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mode2 --driver lirc-rpi --device /dev/lirc0
Driver `lirc-rpi' not found. (Missing -U/--plugins option?)
Available drivers:
accent
alsa_usb
asusdh
atilibusb
atwf83
audio
audio_alsa
awlibusb
bte
bw6130
commandir
creative
creative_infracd
default
devinput
dfclibusb
dsp
dvico
ea65
file
ftdi
ftdi-exp
ftdix
girs
i2cuser
irlink
irtoy
livedrive_midi
livedrive_seq
logitech
macmini
mouseremote
mouseremote_ps2
mp3anywhere
mplay
mplay2
pcmak
pinsys
pixelview
samsung
sb0540
silitek
slinke
sonyir
srm7500libusb
tira
tira_raw
udp
uirt2
uirt2_raw
usb_uirt_raw
usbx
zotac
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is no info what lirc version you are using. There are vast differences between the legacy 0.9.0 still used in some distros and modern lirc.

That said, the logs seems pretty clear. You are using the devinput driver, right? This driver does not support sending data, reflecting the fact that also the kernel doesn't.

You then need to use another driver - first stop might be the default one. If/when using this other driver, you need another lircd.conf.

Please refer to  http://lirc.org/html/configuration-guide.html

EDIT: Ah, lirc-0.9.4c says the log. Sorry, my bad. The reply should still be valid, though.

Comment: Thanks for putting me in the right direction, but I'm still against the driver I'm suppose to use doesn't seem to exist. I updated my post, if you want to take another look.

Comment: The 'default' driver is indeed listed there and exists (bad name, for sure). You still need to read the reference to sort this out, though - lirc configuration isn't trivial.

Answer (score 0):

When you record the remote, use:
irrecord -d /dev/lirc0  -f name.conf

The -f uses raw mode. This then worked for me on the transmit side, before I got same error as you.